# java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-realtime-database

In my api explorer I get following error while performing an insert to an endpoint, which inserts some data to firebase.

```
503

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances."
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances."
 }
}
```

Also I am using following code inside an endpoint class where firebase is a static object reference.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setServiceAccount(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/google-services.json"))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://contactifyapp.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

if (firebaseApp == null)
    firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance()
        .getReference();
String data = runMeNow.getData();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
Random rand = new Random();
ref.child(Keys.CONTACT_INFO).child("child").child(Keys.USER_INFO).setValue(jsonObject.get(Keys.USER_INFO));
```

The logs are as following on server:

```
19:30:43.061
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances.
    at com.google.appengine.api.system.SystemServiceImpl.translateException(SystemServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.api.system.SystemServiceImpl.startBackgroundRequest(SystemServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.google.firebase.database.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$FirebaseThreadFactory.newThread(DefaultRunLoop.java:13)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:600)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:526)
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.doIdleCheck(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1098)
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.<init>(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:266)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.GaePlatform.newPersistentConnection(GaePlatform.java:128)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.newPersistentConnection(Context.java:195)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.<init>(Repo.java:64)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:87)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(RepoManager.java:28)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(FirebaseDatabase.java:249)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(FirebaseDatabase.java:114)
    at com.safran.contactify.backend.RunMeNowEndpoint.insert(RunMeNowEndpoint.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To use Firebase with App Engine, you must use manual scaling. This is because Firebase uses background threads to listen for changes and App Engine only allows long-lived background threads on manually scaled backend instances.
Add following configuration to your `appengine-web.xml`

```
<manual-scaling>
   <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```

Comment: According to the docs this means that there will be just one instance of the service regardless of the amount of requests. Does that mean that requests will be executed synchronously one after another, since there's just one instance of our service?
"A service with manual scaling runs continuously the exact same number of instances irrespective of the load level. This allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that rely on the state of the memory over time."

Comment: Yes, the application won't be scalable at all. You'll have some amount of requests that one instance can handle, all other requests will wait in queue.

Comment: How come this is not mentioned in the documents!! :(